# Polyhedron Placement Optimization

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

I want to place one polyhedron(Object) into another (Container). Both the polyhedrons are convex and defined by a set of points and triangles. The container has a constant size. The object can be scaled and should be strictly inside the container. I want to compute the position and orientation for the object which makes it the biggest. Approximate and efficient solutions also help.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A scary problem. Can the polyedra be very complex ?

Comment: Both of them are convex and have less than one hundred vertices.

Comment: Would be interesting to know if the optimal solution always satisfies a geometric constraint such as one face of the inner polyhedron being parallel to one face of the outer, as this would drastically reduce the search space. Unfortunately, this out of my comptence.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for a quick & suboptimal solution, based on ellipsoids:

For both vertex sets, center around the gravity center and normalize the coordinates by computing the equivalent ellipsoid of inertia, giving you a more isotropic set.

For the outer set, find the shortest distance between the faces and the origin; for the inner set, find the farthest distance to a vertex. This gives you two spheres, one enclosed, one enclosing.

Now transform the enclosed sphere to the coordinates of the enclosing one, giving an ellipsoid: the longer axis of the ellipsoid tells you how much you can inflate it to fit in the sphere.

This approximation can be poor if the polyhedra are skewed.

You can slightly improve this solution by drawing rays from the center of the inner polyhedron through all vertices, and hitting the outer polyhedron, possibly giving you an extra growth factor.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, if running-time allows it:

For a fixed pose of the outer polyhedron, the pose of the inner polyhedron is defined by 3 translation and 3 rotation parameters (such as Euler angles) around an arbitrary center.

When these parameters are fixed, casting rays from the center through the inner vertices until you hit the outer polyhedron gives you the allowed scaling factor.

Now the problem is recast as the maximization of a function of 6 variables, with local maxima to be expected. This can be addressed by Hooke & Jeeves steps, the up-hill simplex method (Nelder-Mead) and/or simulated annealing.

I do not recommend to start from the solution in my other answer and stay close to it, as you could be trapped in a local maximum.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. I will try to design an algorithm with the suggested methods.